# Shutdown Hsqldb server when no more clients are connected

Tags: hsqldb, shutdown

I start a hsqldb 1.8 server like this:

java  -cp "%classpath%;.;Y:\PlantOperations\bldPlantOperations\code\lib\jboss\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\ProcessDesigner\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\ShopOperation\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;" org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 file:"C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb" -dbname.0 xdb

I have multiple clients which connect(in no particular order) using jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb;shutdown=true

I want to shutdown Hsqldb server when no more clients are connected.

I read in docs that adding shutdown=true as I have in jdbc url would cause hsqldb to shutdown after no more clients are connected. But I do not see that happening.

I also tried

```
Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("user", "SA");
            info.put("password", "");
            info.put("shutdown", "true");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbString, info);
```

The above also does not cause hsqldb server to shutdown after the last client disconnects.

Any help on this is appreciated

Bala

Answer (score 0):

The `shutdown=true` property works with the in-process connection, not via the server connection.

It may work if you add this property to the database URL in the server startup. This would cause the database to shutdown, which in turn would cause the server to shutdown.

java -cp ... org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 file:"C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true" -dbname.0 xdb

Unrelated to this, you need only one reference to the hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar in your classpath.

Comment: Hi Fredt, When I try to start hsqldb as you suggested with: java -cp ... org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 file:"C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true" -dbname.0 xdb  it does not start. I do not see any java process using 9001

Comment: The three dots after -cp are placeholders for your path string. Replace them with the original or a shortened version.

Comment: java  -cp "%classpath%;.;Y:\PlantOperations\bldPlantOperations\code\lib\jboss\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\ProcessDesigner\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\ShopOperation\hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar;" org.hsqldb.Server -database.0 file:"C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true" -dbname.0 xdb is what it looks like now

Comment: In that case try starting a server with a server.properties file containing the db path and name as properties without the double quotes. The auto-shutdown may or may not work, but the server should start.

Comment: Reason for having multiple jars is I have different clients(i.e.apps) which when installed drop the hsqldb jar into different folders. Any of these clients could be launched first and would be responsible to ensure a hsqldb server is started if one does not exist. The other clients just connect to the server. Since I am not aware of which client is being launched I opt to put in all the possible places jars could be in classpath.

Comment: Fred, without the auto shutdown I am able to launch and connect the server fine. having a separate properties file is not an option because we have already a release out and there is an installed base. Until next release I have to work within this structure. Are there any other means of achieving the same result.

Comment: Is it possible to issue a set command similar to  'SET WRITE_DELAY 0 MILLIS' for this. i.e SET SHUTDOWN TRUE

Comment: Figured out a way to implement this. Instead of starting a separate process for hsqldb start a thread which starts hsqldb. Each client then tries to just connect if it fails it starts hsqldb.